# Fit video stream in positionned canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-video

In a webapp on mobile I display a video stream on full screen (i.e 360 x 520) using `.getUserMedia`. Depending values passed in URL (i.e 260 x 220) I create a canvas in the middle of the screen:

```
    let largview = iw-40;                             // canvas width with left 20px (iw=screen width)
    let heightview = Math.round((largview)/w)*h;      // URL values
    let topview = Math.round((ih-heightview)/2);      // (ih=screen height)

    video.style.width = iw+'px';
    video.style.height = ih+'px';
    canvas.width = largview;
    canvas.height = heightview;
    canvas.style.marginLeft = 20+'px';
    canvas.style.marginTop = topview+'px';
```

Once done I duplicate the video stream in this canvas:

```
    setInterval(function(){
        context.drawImage(cameraVideo, 20,topview, largview,heightview, 0,0, largview,heightview);
    },1);
```

My prob is that I'm unable to display the video in canvas just as this one was "transparent": without its `border:1px solid red` you couldn't see it, video stream and canvas stream will perfectly fit together. I've tried a lot of different values in `drawImage` but sometimes canvas stream is largest than video stream, sometimes its not at the right place, sometimes its works well (top/left are OK) but canvas is not fully filled: 20px missing on the right side...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a [weird ?] solution with 2 <canvas> tags:

The 1st canvas is set to width and height = 100% (contains the full video stream).

The 2nd one is sized largview * heightview, with position = 20px left and topview px of the top.

```
    setInterval(function(){
    
        cameraContext.drawImage(cameraVideo,  0,0,  iw,ih); // full video
        
        let imageData = cameraContext.getImageData( 20, topview, cameraCanvas.width, cameraCanvas.height);
        cameraContext2.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
        
    },1);
```

Works well.